# html helper link not working in ie

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

I have the following html code:

```
 <div class="main">
   <div class="container">
     <button class="btn btn-default">
        @Html.ActionLink("Explore", "Explore")
    </button>
    </div> </div>
```

The button is styled as below:

```
.main .btn{
 margin-left:600px;
-moz-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
-o-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
background: transparent;
border:1px solid #7b278e;
}
.main .btn a{
    color:#7b278e;
    text-decoration:none;
 }

.main .btn:hover{
    box-shadow:3px 3px 6px #7b278e;
    font-weight:600;
    border:1px solid #7b278e;
 }
```

The link works fine in chrome, but not in IE. Ive not much idea about browser compatibility. Plz help!

The link appears on IE source code as a button with 'Explore' link.
     
        [Explore](/Home/Explore)
     
But on clicking its not going to the 'Explore' View. Nothing is happening.

Comment: When you say "not working", is the anchor put onto the page? Or does it not link to the correct page?

Comment: And what version(s) of IE?

Comment: @epascarello: M using IE11

Comment: @LewisSpears the link does appear on the page. Its not redirecting to the 'Explore' View when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You have a link *inside* a button. Frankly, I'm surprised it worked in any other browser. Since a button of type "button" (the default, if left unspecified) has no inherent action, IE is ironically doing exactly what it should do.

More than likely, your goal here is to have the link styled as a button. The way to do that is not to wrap it in a button element, but to apply the Bootstrap button classes *to* the link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Explore", "Explore", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing it out. That was a silly mistake. 
Somehow overlooked the html helper way of adding class to a link. Thnx again